# how to reference count(*) as a variable in where clause along with group by clause

Tags: sql, count, group-by, db2

I'm using DB2 and trying to restrict a query which uses group by to only include counts larger than some threshold but cannot get past the syntax errors

```
select val, count(*) as c from sample_table
where c > 20
group by val;
```

It doesn't like the fact that I'm referencing c and using it in where clause.

How do I achieve something like this?

Comment: You want a `having` clause, not a `where` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select *
from (
select val, count(*) as c 
from sample_table
group by val
)
where c > 20
```

but better to do:

```
select val, count(*) as c 
from sample_table
group by val
having count(*) > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING`:

```
select val, count(*) as c 
from sample_table
group by val;
having count(*)> 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aggregate functions in where clauses,so you have to use HAVING.

```
select val, count(*) as c
from sample_table
group by val
Having c>20;
```